Drilling hole for power outlet in small tile
I had an idea to add power outlet to kitchen. For it to not remove too many tiles and to look good I thought about placing it in center of tile. And now I'm concerned if it's even possible to drill hole in the tile without breaking it. I'm concerned that the width of the tile parts in the thinnest part will be around 2 centimeters or maybe less. I don't have a spare. I have a diamond drill and some experience in drilling tiles.
Here are some pictures showing situation and the drill.





What country are you in?

@AloysiusDefenestrate in Poland, does it matter in this case?

Matters because junction boxes and receptacles are locally sized. In North America, that would be a rectangular cutout.

(Which is why, in retrospect, I didn’t even recognize the orange-red thing in your picture.)

It is not difficult to drill a hole in ceramic tile, but takes care and patience. Also expect some cracked glaze around the hole, which should be covered by the outlet cover. Since you've already removed the tile, use a drill press with slow and gentle feed, with water lubricant.  BTW, those tiles seem standard -- you should find it easy to take it into a shop to purchase a tile matching in size and color.

Rule 1 : Lubricate (water) Rule 2: do not push, Rule 3: find a old tile and practice

Alright, thank you all for responses, I feel more confident now. Maybe local tile shop will have similar tiles so I'll practice on it and/or will have spare.

The tlle shop will probably have a tile drilling expert also.
